# Printing out the sum of rows in a 2D array using a loop

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I want to print out my array first then the summation of each row, after my full array, using a nested for loop. But, it seems that nothing else happens after my first nested for loop that assigns values to my 2D array. I want it to look like:
The sum of the 1st row is: ...
The sum of the 2nd row is ... and so on until the last row.
Here is what I have so far.

My code:

```java
public class RowsSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 1;
        int[][] nums = new int[5][3]; //declaring a 2D array of type int
        for (int i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums[0].length; j++) {
                num *= 2;
                nums[i][j] = num;
                System.out.print(nums[i][j] + "\t");
            }//closing inner loop
            System.out.println("");
        }// closing nested for loop
        int sum = 0;
        int row = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++) { //second nested for loop
            row++;
            for (int j = 0; j < nums[0].length; j++) {
                sum = sum + nums[i][j];
            }//closing inner loop
            System.out.println("The sum of the " + row + "is" + sum + "\t");
            System.out.println("");
        }// closing nested for loop
    }// closing main method
}//closing class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not re-initializing the sum variable to 0 before traversing through the row.  Also, it's not clear what your second double for-loop is trying to accomplish with this code:

```
num *= 2;
nums[i][j] = num;
```

This repeated code is actual altering the values in the array, you should remove it, it is causing unwanted effects.

Adjust to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <nums.length; i++){ //second Outer loop
  sum = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < nums[0].length; j++){ 
    sum = sum + nums[i][j];          
  }//closing inner loop
  
  System.out.println("The sum of row " + (i+1) + " is " + sum);
}
```

Also, the nested for-loops are in fact the inner loops not the outer loops.

EDIT: You are actually also accessing outside of the bounds of the original array, specifically in the outer loops.  You have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= nums.length; i++)
```

Change it to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
```

Note the small change of <= to <, its subtle yet important since arrays are 0 indexed in java so in an array of length 5, the maximum index will be 4.

Comment: When I do this, it still does not print out anything from the second nested loop.. It only prints my array values for the first nested loop.

Comment: You were actually accessing outside of the bounds of the 2D array, when I ran the code I got an arrayOutOfBounds exception which told me about this.  See the edit in my answer for more information.  Also, as a general note, familiarize yourself with debugging in your favorite IDE, it will really help.

Comment: The reason you were not seeing anything after is because your program was terminating early due to the error.

Comment: OH I see! Thank you very much! this was just was I was looking for.

Comment: Of course!  As a side note, its nice to have this luxury with java until you work in C and accessing out of bounds won't necessarily throw an error.